# Setting custom header field returns unknown

Tags: boost-beast

I'm inserting a custom field in a HTTP request via

```
req.insert("some-custom-header-field-name", "some-value");
```

On the server side I fetch field names via

```
boost::beast::http::to_string(field.name()).data()
```

However, instead of the expected field name it will be

```
<unknown-field>
```

How do I set custom field names in Beast?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's required to use field.name_string() instead of the to_string() method which I was using. The latter resolves to an unknown field in this case.